# Get all data from a paginated response

Tags: python, api, flask, request

I am making a request from an endpoint which is paginated, the endpoint correctly returns just the first page with a link to the second page. I want to return all the data at once.

Here is my code

```
response = requests.get("https://swapi.dev/api/starships/")
```

I've tried **?max=26** and **?limit=26** but no luck.

sample response:

```
{
  "count": 36, 
  "next": "http://swapi.dev/api/starships/?page=2", 
  "previous": null, 
  "data": [
    {
      "MGLT": "60",.....}
      ]

}
```

Please how can I return all the 36 elements at once?

Comment: Do you know that it is possible to get all the pages with only one request?

Comment: I don't. Please how can I go about that?

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the documentation. Here is the link to the documentation: https://swapi.dev/documentation

Comment: Can you clarify whether you were trying to get all the data with a single request, or just wanted to loop and make multiple requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most beautiful solution but working:

```py
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    starships = list()
    next_url = 'https://swapi.dev/api/starships/?page=1'
    
    while next_url:
        query_results = requests.get(next_url).json()
        starships.extend(query_results['results'])
        next_url = query_results['next']
```

Comment: This isn't getting all the data at once though, right?

Comment: Yes, as you can see, separate requests for every page are made, so it could be a problem in some cases.

Comment: Right, so does it really address OP's question?

Comment: First, I mentioned it is not the best solution. Second, it was accepted by the OP, so it simply means that the OP received an answer that worked for him personally.